# What causes fluctuations in share prices every second?

Tags: india, shares

I am currently sitting on web (Zerodha site) and the 197 shares I bought for Rs 70 is now fluctuating between 65.5 to 70.25 appx. So what are the factors that are causing this? How long do one wait before selling?

Comment: @nanoman - Your link doesn't  address ** fluctuations in share prices every second**.

Answer (score 1):

Stock price changes by the second for two reasons.

When buying and selling is in equilibrium, share price is static with  purchases  occurring at the ask price and sales occurring at the bid price.

Stock prices go higher or lower because of supply and demand. When all shares at the bid or all shares at the ask are taken out, price shifts to the next order in the order book.  For example, a heavily traded stock like AAPL has over 1,000 accepted bids per second.

Answer (score 1):

In the most immediate sense, stock price is determined by supply and demand, that is, by how many people want to buy versus how many people want to sell. When more people want to buy than want to sell, the price goes up until some of the buyers decide it's not worth the higher price, and/or more people who own the stock decide it's worth selling at the higher price, and the number of buyers and sellers balances. Reverse that for when more people want to sell than want to buy.

Some stocks are very active and people are trading constantly. So yes, the price can change by the minute or even by the second.

But what determines the supply and demand? Many factors. Obviously, how well the company is doing. When companies announce their latest profit figures the stock price usually goes up or down depending on how good they are. If a company announces a new product that many people expect will sell well, the share price will go up. If something bad happens to the company -- the CEO is arrested, or many other things less dramatic -- the share price will go down. These sort of things can happen at any time. Again, for a big company, there may be some news about the company every day that affects the share price. For Sally's Diner on the corner, not so much.